# VBA: Renaming the active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've run into an issue that seems to be straight forward, but for whatever reason, is giving me an error message in my code.  I'm using a Macro to create a Pivot Table and would like to rename the sheet that is created for the Pivot Table.  My only problem is that the active sheet will not rename and error message "Run-time 9: Subscript out of range" is given .  The code is below and the error occurs on the last line:

```
Sub Macro24()

Dim VendorData As String
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim PivotSheet As String

Sheets("Statement").Select
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Statement").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="VendorData", RefersTo:= _
    "=Statement!$A$4:$C$" & Lastrow

Sheets.Add
PivotSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: Which line is producing the Run-time 9 error? This error means that the object you are referring in the code is not available in the workbook. Are you getting that error with the line Sheets("Statement").Select? If so, make sure that the sheet called Statement is available. Otherwise the last two lines of the code you showed are not supposed to produce that error.

Comment: The very last line PivotSheet = ActiveSheet.Name is where I get the error.  It's simply not renaming the active sheet to PivotSheet

Comment: Also what's the point of getting the activesheet's name into the variable PivotSheet? Are you going to use it later in the code? If you just want to rename the sheet after it is added, just use ActiveSheet.Name="Pivot Sheet"

Comment: Yes I'm going to use the variable;e later in the code to create the Pivot Table.  Unless there is another way that does not involve creating the variable that you know of

Comment: I cannot digest why would you get the error with the last line. Is the actual code similar what you showed in the description?

Comment: Yes, the code is the exact same as shown in the description.  It is a mystery to me as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156947/discussion-between-sktneer-and-oryan5000).

Comment: Your description and code do not seem to match. What you should be doing is `ActiveSheet.Name = PivotSheet` and not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks so much! I changed the code to Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotSheet"
    PivotSheet = ActiveSheet.Name   and that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use worksheet variable:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.name = "PivotSheet"
pivotsheet = ws.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!  I am however still getting the same error message on the same line after making the changes

Comment: YOu are assigning the new sheet (which will be something like Sheet3 ) to Pivotsheet. Is there some other code missing that might be the problem? What line does it error at? You are not renaming the active sheet.

Comment: It errors out at the very last line in my code above because the sheet is not renamed.  All of the code above is included. How do I actually rename the sheet using a variable?

Comment: You are not renaming the sheet in your code your are placing the name of the new sheet in a variable called pivotsheet. And this work for me without issue. @oryan5000

Comment: @oryan5000 if you want to change a worksheet's name, then the `Name` property of that `Worksheet` instance needs to show up on the left-hand side of an assignment, somewhere. That's nowhere in your code, hence, you are not renaming any worksheet, and it's not clear where you intend to be doing that or what the new name ought to be.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I changed the code and it worked! Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotSheet"
    PivotSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Comment: @oryan5000 **seriously** consider following Scott's advice, and keep a reference to the added worksheet object reference, and work against that, instead of assuming what the `ActiveSheet` is. This *will* bite you in the rear end, sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly keep that in mind and change my code